# How can i create Generated/Computed column Postgres/DJANGO?

Tags: django, postgresql, calculated-columns

How can I create Generated/Computed column Postgres/DJANGO?

I tried in both ways:

(1) By a Class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    precio_costo = models.FloatField(null=True)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    monto_stock = models.FloatField(
        always_generated='precio_costo * cantidad', stored=True)
```

ERROR I GET:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'always_generated'

(2) Directly by POSTGRES Admin

But I can't update or add a new field, Default value is required by Django.

Comment: Please explain... what you were doing? What problem you encounterd? What methods you tried to solve the problem ?

Comment: `always_generated` doesn't seem to be a thing. Why did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have the result `monto_stock` stored in the database?

If no, then maybe just use a Python method/property on the class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    precio_costo = models.FloatField(null=True)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    @property
    def monto_stock(self):
        return self.precio_costo * self.cantidad
```

If yes, then maybe calculate the result in the models `save()` method:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    precio_costo = models.FloatField(null=True)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    monto_stock = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.monto_stock = self.precio_costo * self.cantidad
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just be carefull: your fields allow NULL, so there will be errors if any field actually contains the value NULL (because you cannot do NULL/None multiplication in Python).

Do any of these options work for you?

---

EDIT: in case of option 1, to use the property `monto_stock` in your view you can simply access it like any other attribute of an model (but it will be read-only). For example:

```
# get a single product
p = Product.objects.first()
print(p.monto_stock)

# get sum of all products
print(sum(p.monto_stock for p in Product.objects.all()))
```

Just note that because it is a Python class property and not a DB field, it can NOT be used in database queries directly this way.

```
# will NOT work
print(Product.objects.aggregate(Sum('monto_stock'))))
```

Comment: Lets say for example i will not store these values on my db.

How can i access "def monto_stock" SUM, on my views.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have also find always_generated solution in django project website.
After trying so many things finally one approach works for me.

That is just **REMOVE** or **COMMENT** all those columns entry from models.py which have the db triggers.

Eg: auto increment columns, current timestamp columns, generated as columns etc.

```
# requesttimestamp = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='RequestTimeStamp', always_generated='createddate')  # Here I was getting that error.
# createddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedDate', auto_now_add=True)
```

So I commented these two lines and it worked as expected.

Also no need to pass anything while creating instance to save record.